# How to put required validation in javascript innerhtml input box

Tags: javascript

```
function edit_row(id)
{
    document.getElementById("monthly_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='monthly_text"+id+"' value='"+monthly+"' onkeyup='this.value=Comma(this.value)' 'required'>"; 
}
```

The above code is an example of my input field and i want to put required validation so that the data will not be saved when the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

if you have textbox id then you can easily find and then you can check input empty or not. you need use this process before saving data.

```
 document.getElementById("monthly_val" + id).innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='monthly_text" + id + "' value='" + monthly + "' onkeyup='this.value=Comma(this.value)'>";
if ($('#monthly_text' + id + '').val() == '') { alert('wala'); }
```

use this. it helps you

Comment: what do you mean by heave sir?

Comment: that's my mean [
if you have textbox id then you can easily find and then you can check input empty or not. you need use this process before saving data.]

Comment: i hava a textbox id sir.

Comment: if ($('#id').val() != '') {
    ///do something here.
}


it's my mean

Comment: thank you sir but it didnt work on my code  if ($('monthly_text"+id+"').val() == '') {

  alert('wala');
}

Comment: document.getElementById("monthly_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='monthly_text"+id+"' value='"+monthly+"' onkeyup='this.value=Comma(this.value)'>"; 
                                                            
 if($('#monthly_text"+id+"').val() == '') 
   { alert('wala'); }

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var a = document.getElementById("monthly"+id),
b = document.createElement("INPUT");
b.setAttribute("pattern", "regexp string");
b.setAttribute("formnovalidate", " false");
b.setAttribute("type", "text");
//add other attributes
a.appendChild(b);

/*
Just replace the regexp string*/
```

Comment: what will i replace with the regexp string user8118986?

Comment: @SantanaOrtega Like this "[\s\w]+" which means you only allow whitespace and alphabets and underscore.

Comment: @SantanaOrtega Or "[\w\d:;$.]+" which can be useful for password because it only allows letters, numbers, and the following symbols.

Comment: thank you for that @user8118986. i tried that one but it did not work on the my code